# Android - Changing Locale language within the app itself

Tags: android, locale, setlocale

My app supports 3 languages (english, french and arabic). I have already translated all ressources (values string and drawables files) and it work perfect according to the language set in the user device.

The app consists principally of two activities : mainActivity and Game Activity. mainActivity contain a button (Play) which leads to the GameActivity according to the device language. For example if language is english it will launch **Game** Activity, if f language is french it will launch **GameFr** Activity, and if language is arabic it will launch **GameAr** Activity.

```
Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar")){
        Intent intgame=new Intent(MainActivity.this,GameAr.class);
        startActivity(intgame);
    }

    else {
        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("fr")){
            Intent intgame=new Intent(MainActivity.this,GameFr.class);
            startActivity(intgame);
        }

        else {
            Intent intgame=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Game.class);
            startActivity(intgame);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

However, I would like to add 3 ImageView (flags) in the MainActivity through which users can change the language of the application, for this I added the following:

```
en = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.en);
fr = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fr);
ar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ar);

en.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    setLocale("en");
    Intent uo = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Game.class);
    startActivity(uo);
    }
});

fr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    setLocale("fr");
    Intent uo = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GameFr.class);
    startActivity(uo);
    }
});

ar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    setLocale("ar");
    Intent uo = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GameAr.class);
    startActivity(uo);
    }
});
```

Nevertheless, when a user with a device which the language is set to english click the French flag, it will get successfully the french activity. However, if he comes back to the previous page and click on the button (Play), the page displayed is the one corresponding to the activity in English but with the resources (string values and Drawables) French.

This is because the following function:

```
if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar"))
```

always test the language of the device, not the language that the user chose in     the app.

is there a function that can give me the language chosen by the SetLocale function? or I should use a variable transfer between activities?

how can I fix this, do you have better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
 Locale.setDefault("Your Locale");
```

Comment: Where ? in the if statement ? if you notice I set a test on the button (Play) to get the right Activity according to the language. So if it's possible I need to replace "if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("fr"))" by another function that get the language set by the user (see the SetLocale function) and not the device default langugage

Comment: Inside your setLocale() method.

Comment: Check Locale.java class for existing locales.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works like a charm. I wasn't expecting such a quick response. Thank you again.